# Comparing String with String Values

Tags: java, string, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

I have a string called `DomainType`  which usually holds values like "edu,com,org..etc" from a url. I used an if else statement to help check the data type and output a `JOptionPane`. For some reason whenever you type any domain type, It gives you the last option.

Here is a Snippet from the code I wrote:

```
DomainType = URL.substring(URLlength - 3, URLlength);

if (DomainType == "gov") {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a Government web address.");
}
else if (DomainType == "edu") {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a University web address.");
}
else if (DomainType == "com") {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a Business web address.");
}
else if (DomainType == "org") {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is a Organization web address");
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This is an unknown web address type.");
}
```

so the `DomainType` gives me edu or com no problem but i think it's my if statement I'm not doing right.

Comment: I wonder how many millions of hours have been wasted due to the Java designers deciding to use == this way... We'll probably see the same questions pop up for ever... sigh

Comment: Yep really an annoying limitation. Oh well

Comment: Why should the "==" operator work differently for `String` than any other object? That would be stupid... even more stupid than the string concatenation operator looking the same as the arithmetic addition operator.

Answer (score 4):

When comparing strings, never use `==`, use `equals`. So, instead of

```
DomainType == "org"
```

use

```
DomainType.equals("org")
```

Why? `==` will compare references. That means: memory values. And they may not be equal for your strings. `equals` will compare values, and that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

To compare content use `equals`, not `==` (which compares references):

```
if (DomainType.equals("gov")) {
```

Comment: It's right,'==' is often used when compare object references.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, a mega-if is probably not the most elegant way to do that - http://www.antiifcampaign.com/ - sorry, just being pedantic.

The .equals() method is the right way to compare objects indeed.